# Simple Record Chatter without costly Community+ licence

Tags: community, chatter, licenses, experience-cloud, sharing-sets

I am wrapping my head around the substantial differences between Community and Community Plus licenses.

I have a Managed Package that wants to engage external users, and I am trying to make it work with the cheaper Community Licences.

- Our custom object. `Project__c` OWD is Private
- each record might be accessed by a different set of community users
- users might access multiple records
- we would like to allow collaboration between external users and internal users; internal users can ask questions and create polls and external users are invited to collaborate.

**Sharing Set vs. Share records**

With Sharing Set, there is no link between the Contacts users and Project__c. Project__Share records for selected users work perfectly but require a CC+ license.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Community Plus license is only needed if you need complex sharing rules like for example you want to have a role hierarchy in place to share record or you would need to write Apex and create Sharing rules via Apex Managed Sharing.

I suggest you refer to this [guide](https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Sharing-in-Communities-Uncovering-the-best-sharing-option-for-your-external-use-cases) for more in-depth understanding on the capabilities.

For requirements you have at this point from what's listed you cannot do this with the Community license. Because of the complexity your sharing requirements you will need customer community plus license.

Comment: That's great @Mohit but did you hear that I want to using Sharing to get external users access to Object + Chatter. I thought I simple add them as Readers to the Sharing Table on this Community enabled Custom object and they will see it. Is that possible with Community?

Comment: Only way you can add this is via Sharing set if license is customer community type. If you can accomplish using Sharing set customer community license should be fine.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava that guide is really something. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava could you please revistit your answer and comments as I clarified our requirements and issues?

Comment: Clarified to make it more relevant to your updates